# App crashes when I change orientation on tablet with ClientErrorCode: 3

Tags: android, androidx

I have created an app using AndroidX in which I simply display some records in a RecyclerView. On my emulated phone works fine in both orientations portrait and landscape but on my emulated tablet, on portrait works fine but when I change the orientation to landscape the app crashes with this error:

```
2019-08-03 15:37:56.804 3167-9341/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/EntrySyncManager: Cannot determine account name: drop request
2019-08-03 15:37:56.810 3167-9341/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/NowController: Failed to access data from EntryProvider. ExecutionException.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.android.apps.gsa.sidekick.main.h.n: Could not complete scheduled request to refresh entries. ClientErrorCode: 3
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.eA(SourceFile:85)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.get(SourceFile:23)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.l.get(SourceFile:2)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbB(SourceFile:49)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbA(SourceFile:181)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.bh.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.at.run(SourceFile:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.i.run(SourceFile:6)
 Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.sidekick.main.h.n: Could not complete scheduled request to refresh entries. ClientErrorCode: 3
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.ar.az(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.q.ap(SourceFile:7)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.p.run(SourceFile:32)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.bt.execute(SourceFile:3)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.b(SourceFile:275)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.addListener(SourceFile:135)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.p.b(SourceFile:3)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.h.a(SourceFile:16)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.h.a(SourceFile:13)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbB(SourceFile:47)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbA(SourceFile:181) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.bh.run(Unknown Source:2) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.at.run(SourceFile:4) 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source:4) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.i.run(SourceFile:6)
```

I've seen some solutions but none of them worked for me. Please help.

Comment: Try to add in manifest :android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Comment: @Kabir Same result :(

Comment: Don't use that manifest attribute. It's a hack workaround that will only cause pain in the long run.

Comment: @BenP. Ok, so do you have any solution for this issue?

Comment: Try recreating the emulated tablet, making sure the hardware properties are the same as those found on the emulated phone.

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException Just checked and are the same :| It crashes only on tablet when changing orientation.

Comment: Have you tried making a new one?

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException Yes, I tried also that and it's the same issue. I tried also with different types of tablets, same behavior.

Comment: How about a new phone?

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException On a new phone works as on the old one, perfect. What might cause this error on tablet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197449/discussion-between-insurgentpointerexception-and-lilian-sorlanski).

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException No, there is a single layout for all devices, why?